# No command line utility for express/node windows 7

Tags: node.js, express, command-prompt

I can't run the command `express` from the windows 7 command line. A tutorial I am following ([here](http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/08/node-tutorial-2/)) suggests that I use the command line and call express to build a skeleton application.

I move into the directory of the express module in my node_modules area and attempt to locate a batch file or executable that is able to run from the command line.

I have found nothing, there are no files included in the module that can be run from the command line.

I am now very confused.

Does anyone understand where this elusive express command line utility exists?

Comment: To use a package via command-line, if it has any "binaries," install it globally with the `--global` or `-g` option -- `npm install -g express`. Also, be cautious of taking the guide word-for-word. Being over 2 years old, it's almost certainly out of date in some of the finer details. E.g., much of the `express` code would've been written against 1.x while the current 3.x has seen [quite a few changes](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the batch file.

All command files for modules that are meant to be invoked via the command prompt are found in `node_modules\.bin`

So make sure that is in your path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jonathan Lonowski was right - the guide is a bit outdated.  The latest command for using the express generator is:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

This will still give the same directory structure suggested in the tutorial.
More info on [Express's Github page](https://github.com/strongloop/express#quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **Express application generator**, as described in Express [Getting started](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html) document. Install it with the following command:

```
 $ npm install express-generator –g
```

After that, you can run the command `express` from any windows 7 command line.